# ¿Como puedo cambiar el efecto de un texto usando el scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, bootstrap

mi pregunta es simple o eso creo xD. Quiero que al bajar el scroll cambien los colores de un texto ya sea que se inviertan los colores o las clases en su defecto x.x Y no tengo idea de como hacerlo, creo que con jquery pero realmente no soy bueno en eso.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Testing </title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <style>
     body{
       height: 1000px
     }
     .hola{
       color: white;
     }
     .mundo{
       color: red;
     }
   </style>
   <p class="hola">Hola <span class="mundo">Mundo</span></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Olvidé decir que el "hola mundo" es un navbar fixeado. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola para lograr eso es muy fácil, tienes que añadir al body el evento [scroll](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp)

`<body onscroll="myFunction()">`

Luego en tu función debes de detectar a que posición está el scroll vertical con `window.scrollY`

Entonces la función quedaría algo parecido a

```
function myFunction() {

    if(window.scrollY > 0)
        document.getElementById(id).style.color  = 'black';
    else
        document.getElementById(id).style.color  = 'white';

}
```

Ejemplo: (Para poder visualizarlo recuerda que el elemento tiene que estar fijo o nov eras el cambio al realizar el scroll)

```js
function funcion() {
    
        if(window.scrollY > 0)
            document.getElementById("hola").style.color  = 'black';
        else
            document.getElementById("hola").style.color  = 'white';
    
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Testing </title>
  </head>
  <body onscroll="funcion()">
   <style>
     body{
       height: 1000px
     }
     .hola{
       color: white;
     }
     .mundo{
       color: red;
     }
     p {
     position: fixed;
     }
   </style>
   <p id="hola" class="hola">Hola <span class="mundo">Mundo</span></p>
  </body>
</html>
```